# Modeling publication with multiple authors belonging to multiple instutes in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, many-to-many, one-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to come up with a sensible SQLite database schema for the following situation.

I have a database containing publications. Each of these publications has a number of authors, and each of these authors can belong to a number of different institutes. It is possible however, that multiple authors share an institute. For example, a publication has authors Anne, Bert and Carl. Anne belongs to institute A and B, Bert belongs to B and C, and Carl belongs to C, D and E.

The number of authors per publication should be variable, as should the number of institutes any particular author can belong to. Institutes should be represented only once, though.

Right now, I am thinking of the following schema:

```
create table publications (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    ...
)

create table publication_institutes (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    publication_id integer references publications(id),
    ...
)

create table publication_authors (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    publication_id integer references publications(id),
    ...
)

create table publication_author_institute (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    institude_id integer references publication_institutes(id),
    author_id integer references publication_authors(id)
)
```

This seems suboptimal though. `publication_author_institute` has no reference anymore to the id in `publications`, but putting it there explicitly also seems off.

Is there a clear solution to this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to know what institutions an author ever has belonged to, or which he belonged to while publishing a specific publication?

Comment: I need to know which authors belong to a specific publication, as well as to which institute they belonged while publishing that publication. Multiple authors might belong to the same institute for a given publication.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a schema that has Authors, Publications, and Institutes, and then many-to-many tables for the relationships of Authors-to-Institutes and Authors-to-Publications.

For example:

```
author
id    name     other info (lastname, title, etc) 
 1    Anne     ...
 2    Bert     ...
 3    Carl     ...

institute
id    name    other info (address, city, state, etc)
 1      A     ...
 2      B     ...
 3      C     ...
 4      D     ...
 5      E     ...

publication
id   title            journal          year    issue
 1   How to Publish   Weekly Journal   2011      5
 2   What I Do        Monthly Mag      2013      1
 3   How Are We       Ranger Rick      2014      9

author_affiliation
id   author_id    inst_id
 1       1           1
 2       1           2
 3       2           2
 4       2           3
 5       3           3
 6       3           4
 7       3           5
 (for this table, could also use author_id-inst_id as a composite PK,
 and get rid of the id column, as in the next table)

publication_author  (here i'm using the composite PK)
pub_id    auth_id    position
  1          1          1
  1          2          2
  2          1          2
  2          3          1
  3          3          1
(position indicates order of authorship, which is important)
```

In the long run, this makes maintenance of the database easier, as a change in affiliation just requires dropping a record from the author_affilitation table, without needing to make any changes to institute or author entries. For publications, you will have to enter a record both for publication and publication_author, but it avoids having to deal with columns with multiple values (like an 'authors' column in publication table).

Likewise, if you want to query for all publication by an author, you can query publication_authors with a join on publication and author tables.

It's the schema I'd use for reducing redundancy and giving flexibility in querying later on.